# Please make sure your database server is running at `localhost`:`5432` - Prisma Nest js -Down migration error

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, prisma

I am using Nest js + Prisma + Postgres in the Backend of my website.  I am trying to down migrate
by following the document https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/developing-with-prisma-migrate/generating-down-migrations it is working fine until it reached this command.

```
           npx prisma db execute --file ./down.sql --schema prisma/schema.prisma
```

And it is throwing this error

Error: P1001

Can't reach database server at `localhost`:`5432`

Please make sure your database server is running at `localhost`:`5432`.

I am using Prisma 3.15 .all other commands work fine I am getting this error when I run

```
  npx prisma db execute --file ./down.sql --schema prisma/schema.prisma
```

Comment: Can you please post the `down.sql` and `schema.prisma` files? I'm assuming there may be an issue with the `down.sql` if other commands are working.

Comment: i have created down.sql file with 
npx prisma migrate diff \ 
 --from-schema-datamodel prisma/schema.prisma \ 
 --to-schema-datasource prisma/schema.prisma \ 
 --script > down.sql 
with this command

Comment: Hey Aneesh, are you running into any error when you run other commands such as `migrate dev`?

Comment: it is working fine